# Send cyclic command to serial port

Tags: bluetooth, macros, ttl, teraterm

I have to execute some tests with a Bluetooth LE module.
For the BT Chip I have an evaluation board here, which I can connect via USB to serial port on my PC.

From the manual of the eval board I learned how to broadcast data from the BT chip using Tera Term. It is just a simple command like "SHW, 0018, AABBCCDD" I have to type in and the BT module will send this data.

Now I want to automate Tera Term, so that this command is executed every 100ms. 
I did some research and I know that I have to use the Tera Term macro language (TTL?), but I'm really not into this program.

Can anybody help me out here with a code snippet or a link to the right explanation? I think, it should be pretty easy?

Additional info: 
I connect to the eval board on USB Serial Port (COM7) with baud rate 115200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
while 1  
  sendln 'SHW, 0018, AABBCCDD'
  mpause 100
endwhile
```

Save it as eg test01.ttl and load it in teraterm like this:

[image]

Also, [here](http://www.teraterm.org/manual/en/macro/command/index.html) you can find a description of TTL commands.

My opinion though, is that you should start using Python and [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) to handle this kind of tasks.